# create new object on button click

Tags: javascript, object, button, onclick

I'm new to javascript and this is strictly for practice. I have an html form (below) and I want the submit button to create a new object using the `Person` constructor when clicked. I want the new object's name to be whatever the user's first name is. For example, if the first name's john it would create a `var john = new Person`.

Form:

```
<form name="theform">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    Age: <input type="number" name="age"><br>
    <input type="button" onClick="new Person()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Constructor:

```
function Person(){
    this.firstname = document.theform.fname.value;
    this.lastname = document.theform.lname.value;
    var age = document.theform.age.value;
    this.returnAge = function(){
        return age;
    }
};
```

Comment: why would you want a dynamically named variable ?

Comment: Interestingly, I never thought of this.

Answer (score 0):

Just put an id to your submit button and do:

```
document.getElementById("submit").onclick=function(){
    var name=document.forms["theform"]["fname"].value;
    window[name]= new Person();
    console.log(window[name])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make sense: why do you want a dynamically named variable?

You refer to a property of an object with `variableName.propertyName`. In this case, that would be `personName.firstname`. *That* is how you would store the first name, **not** as the variable name itself (that wouldn't make sense: how would you refer to the object?).

Comment: You can have dynamically named global variables, and they can be accessed dynamically as well. I don't know what he's ultimately up to, but it's certainly not impossible.

Comment: @cookiemonster Alright; I didn't know about that. Why would you want to do that, though?

Comment: Hard to say. I mean creating globals dynamically isn't too unusual, but this particular example seems contrived. He says it's strictly for practice, so I'm guessing he's just toying with various concepts and seeing how they work.

Comment: @cookiemonster Fair enough.

Comment: ^haha yeah its just for practice. well if i want a new object for each person that submits the form (for whatever reason), wouldn't i need a dynamically named variable? or is there another way to give each user an object based on their first name?

Comment: @user2540029 Only if you were passing that data to a server; if you're only working client-side, just name it something generic and reference it that way.

Comment: actually, i'm planning on doing just that but i obviously have a lot of learning to do. so i'm assuming i would use a server-side language to pass that to a server?

Comment: @user2540029 Yes: you'll probably have to look into [PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php).

Comment: i was thinking about learning java, since that's my company's IT department uses. would that serve the same purpose?

Comment: @user2540029 It certainly *could*, but it's not as commonly used for server-side development as PHP.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form name="theform">
    First name: <input id="myName" type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    Age: <input type="number" name="age"><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="window[document.getElementById('myName').value] = new Person();" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then after that, if you open the console and search for `john` for example, it will return the object.

Works but it's considered bad coding to do it that way.

Comment: This does not answer the question: `john` is not declared anywhere, and the OP wants the variable to be named whatever is in the `fname` field.

Comment: Via `window['nameofvariable']` you can? `window['john'] = 1` is the same than `john = 1;` which is the same than `var str = 'john'; window[str] = 1;`

Comment: JS does allow you to create global variable with the window object... What you wrote: `var document.getElementById("name").value = "John";` makes no sense... but `window[document.getElementById("name").value] = "John";` does.

Comment: What I wrote is also what the OP wants: create a global variable that holds an object and that can be accessed via the name directly. And if he wants a local variable, he can do `eval('var ' + document.getElementById("name").value + ' = new Person()');`